# How to Model Cations or Anions for Activation Energy Barrier Calculation in VASP for Electron Exchange Reactions?

Tags: vasp, computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electronic-structure, reactivity

I am interested in performing activation energy barrier calculations using VASP (Vienna Ab initio Simulation Package) specifically for reactions involving electron exchange. However, I am uncertain about the appropriate methodology for modeling cations or anions within the VASP framework to accurately calculate activation energy barriers for these reactions.

Could someone provide guidance or resources on how to properly model cations or anions in VASP for activation energy barrier calculations, particularly in the context of electron exchange reactions? Any insights into the suitable input parameters, settings, or considerations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered the NELECT tag? this tag would help you set the number of valence electrons, such that for cations, you may need to remove electrons, while for anions, you may need to add electrons. Let's say you have 10 valence electrons in total, set NELECT=9 and that's how you would simulate having a cation.

Comment: Thanks for the info!